# How to split string at operators

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, calculator

Im creating a calculator in Java.

If i have the user enter a string such as:

```
7+4-(18/3)/2
```

So far i have had to have the user enter a space between each number or operator.
How would i create an array from the given string where the string is split at either number or an operator so in this case the array would be:

```
[7, +, 4, -, (, 18, /, 3, ), /, 2]
```

(The array is of type String)

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: What will you do with that array? If you are trying to evaluate the expression, then there are already libraries available for that.

Comment: `String[] splitted= userString.split(" ");` gives your result. But prefer to use existing libraries as @Rohit said.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ how will that help  if all his String don't have space ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ No it doesn't. There are no space indeed.

Comment: But surely this would require there to be spaces already in the String the user inputs?

Comment: @RohitJain Yeah. later he stated. `So far i have had to have the user enter a space between each number or operator.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what you want to do with the array. If you really want to evaluate the expression, then there are already libraries available for that. You can use one of them. But if you only want an array like the one you have shown, then also I wouldn't suggest to use regex. You can write your own parser method like below:

```
public static String[] parseExpression(String str) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder currentDigits = new StringBuilder();

    for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            currentDigits.append(ch);
        } else {
            if (currentDigits.length() > 0) {
                list.add(currentDigits.toString());
                currentDigits = new StringBuilder();
            }
            list.add(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
    }

    if (currentDigits.length() > 0)
        list.add(currentDigits.toString());

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Now call it like:

```
String str = "7+4-(18/3)/2";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseExpression(str)));
```

and you will get your result.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response, it seems to do as intended. However when i enter an expression such as (7-9)/2 it returns         [(, 7, -, 9, ), /], do you know why it would leave the 2? Thanks :)

Comment: This seems to happen whenever the expression ends with a number

Comment: @user3120023 Outside the `for` loop, check if `currentDigits` is empty. If not, then there are digits at the end. Will edit the code.

Comment: Thanks very much :) However it seems to split decimals such as 2.5 into [2, ., 5 ] is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
String[] temp = expression.split("[\s+-\\\(\)]+");
```

will split on:

- white spaces
- `+` operator
- `-` operator
- `\` character
- `(` character
- `)` character

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. When i try your code i get the error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) Have you got any ideas on what caused this?

Comment: Thanks very much, how would also include the * operator? I am also getting the same error again.

Comment: add `\*` in square brackets

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is going to strip away the oeprators.

Comment: -1: Doesn't compile and doesn't match the OP's requirements. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is just scan the string myself to be honest. You will want to build an operation from the results anyway so you don't really gain anything by using an automated parser/splitter/etc.

Here is a rough sketch of the code:

```
List<Operations> ops = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {

   char c = str.get(i);
   if (c == '.' || c >= '0' || c<='9') {
       // extract a number, moving i onwards as I do 
       // insert number into ops (new Operation(num))
   } else if (c!= ' ') {
       Operator operator = operators.get(c);
       if (operator == null) {
           // Handle invalid input - could just skip it
       } else {
           // Add operator to ops
       }
   }
}
```

You would need to define operators for each of the various symbols.

Once you have done that you have parsed the string out to hold only the important data and compiled a list of what operations they are.

Now you need to work out how to process that list of operations applying correct precedence rules etc :) The simplest way may just be to repeatedly loop through the list each time performing each calculation that is valid that time around.

i.e.

```
1+2*(3+4)-(4+2)
```

First pass:

```
1+2*12-6
```

Second pass:

```
1+24-6
```

Result:

```
19
```

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt was to use `"\b"`, but that didn't split `-(`. After some searching, I came up with this:

```
(?<=[\(\)\+\-*\/\^A-Za-z])|(?=[\(\)\+\-*\/\^A-Za-z])
```

So, you will have to escape it and use it like this:

```
String input = ...;
String temp[] = input.split("(?<=[\\(\\)\\+\\-*\\/\\^A-Za-z])|(?=[\\(\\)\\+\\-*\\/\\^A-Za-z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```

Input:

```
7+4-(18/3)/2a^222+1ab
```

Output:

```
[7, +, 4, -, (, 18, /, 3, ), /, 2, a, ^, 222, +, 1, a, b]
```

See it in action here:
http://rubular.com/r/uHAObPwaln
http://ideone.com/GLFmo4